# Eclipse RCP application/product could not correctly run

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, rcp, eclipse-sirius

I have an Eclipse RCP application, which has 2 parts, cdt extension and GMF extension,

1. I create an product configuration, uses application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" with no problems but there are more unexpected menus shown,
2. so I have to use application="com.x.y.z.branding/myown.product" it gives me below errors, even I can use the started application, but creating modeling project doesn't show on modeler explorer.

please help,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.sirius.server.ui.autostart.internal.SiriusServerStartup.lambda$2(SiriusServerStartup.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4034)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3701)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at com.x.y.z.branding.Application.start(Application.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like Eclipse Sirius bug [536894](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536894). The bug report says

- The server auto-start feature and plug-ins do not depend on the server itself, so it is possible to have the auto-start plug-in installed without the server, which triggers the NPE.
- The auto-start feature's description does not clearly mark it as experimental, so users may want to install it "just to see", and then get the NPE.

So you probably need to update the list of plugins in the RCP to include the server.

Comment: I could not have the new model project shown in modeler explorer, even the NullPointerException disappeared while updated eclipse-sirius to version 6.0.1, it includes bug 536894 fix.

Comment: I think it is, you are not including a suitable set of plugins in the RCP causing the code to fail to start properly. The bug explains why this happens and hints at what to do about it.

Comment: Yes, I did not include required plug-ins/features properly, that is why, application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench"  works but myown does not,

Comment: My question is, how do you check what are missing, or in another words saying, how do you check the differences between org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench and myown?